# Implement checkbox for parent node side filter panel ( Ag Grid React )

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Wanted to check if anyone has customized an ag-grid side filter panel to implement a checkbox at the parent element ( having column grouping enabled ).

> Goal

1. In column grouping we want to place a checkbox at a particular level, we have 4 level
   and this changes for every group.
2. When a user clicks on this checkbox we will have to pick a few child filters based on a
   logic and apply them

[image]

> What we have tried

We tried to look for the ability to add a checkbox, but we didn't find a direct way to add a checkbox, to mimic this using css using `:: before` and adding a background image of the checkbox but we wanted to know if there is a better way to achieve this.